# Drip leak from a 2 yr old toilet / bolt

Tags: toilet, leak, bolts

I had my toilet replaced about 2 yrs back with a [Kohler 4467](https://www.us.kohler.com/us/Wellworth-1.28-gpf-tank/). It seems to have developed a drip leak from where it is bolted - a drop or 2 every 30min. I had the plumber who installed it come and look and his response was he might have to change it - about $300.

I contacted Kohler support and their response was "looks like right parts were not used" [K-GP51487](https://www.us.kohler.com/us//productDetail/toilet-gaskets-and-seats/637957.htm?skuId=613403&_requestid=870656). The plumber's response was "those are no good."

Any suggestions on how to fix this w/o having to remove the whole thing apart (not too handy). Will the silicone caulk used in shower/kitchen work/ help?

[image: Source of the leak]

[image: Tank inside]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you take the word of the plumber? He installed the wrong parts, which now leak. He also says he knows more than Kohler. Three strikes against him.

How about taking the word of Kohler, who made the toilet and knows which parts work? Wouldn't that be a safer bet? And if you go this route and can't fix the toilet yourself, will you make the same mistake again by hiring the same plumber?

Comment: I general I agree with you, but there are some who manage to know quite a bit more about the product they're working with and how to make it work better or differently than the company who manufactured it does. I don't believe that's the case in this situation, though.

Comment: Replacing those bolts (with correct nuts, washers, and seals) is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

The leak looks like it might be from the washer being folded on the bolt on the right (when you are facing the toilet).  The rubber has not made a good seal.  The job to fix it is very easy.

1. Turn off the water going to the tank (there is usually an 'oval plastic knob' to turn
2. Keep flushing the toilet (this will drain the water from the tank)
3. Undo the bolt with a flat head screw driver and/or a wrench on the underside of the tank.
4. Either unfold or replace the rubber washer.
5. Tighten up the screw (don't go crazy tight since it may crack the porcelain but you need to make it water tight)
   I should mention-- if you only have 1 toilet, make sure that everyone uses it before you start the job and that you have a couple of rubber washers on hand (any hardware store).
   Good luck